# substrn in Crystal report and Oracle SQl

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, substr

I am working on crystal report and Oracle SQL developer.

I have a field, Birthdate like `01-JAN-92` and I want to extract the year in numerical form. 
92 in the case above.

I used `substr("p.Birthdate",8,2)` function to extract 92 and it works fine in oracle sql,
but when I copy the query from Oracle to Crystal Report, no data is coming in Crystal Report.

I tried MID function too, and Oracle SQL developer, Crystal Report just don't recognise the mid function.

Comment: `Mid()`is a Crystal function so I don't know what you mean when you say that it isn't "recognized". Can you post your formula?

Comment: select mid("Birth",8,2) as BYEAR from PATIENT;

Comment: this is just the simple query that i am trying  to put in crystal report as a command

Comment: Is there any other function i can use to extract the year in numerical value ?
That was the main problem

Comment: Just put the valid SQL in the command since that just gets run on the Oracle server anyway. Don't use Crystal functions or syntax in either SQL Commands or SQL Expressions.

Comment: you have to call the pivot qurey for this

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple `TO_CHAR("p.Birthdate",'YYYY')`

if you want the year with just two digits, that would be better `TO_CHAR("p.Birthdate",'RR')`